# Iphone SDK: change image color

Tags: iphone, image, colors

In cocos2d, there's an option to "change" a sprite's color. For example: I have a white image, then I execute the code and the image turns to any color that I specify. How can I do the same thing without using the cocos2d libraries?

I know it's possible and I did such a thing myself about 5 months ago, but in typical fashion I somehow managed to lose the code.

Comment: Create CGContext, draw image into context, get pixel data, iterate, modify and save.

Comment: It may also useful for you.
https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UIImage *newImage = [_imgView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, newImage.scale);
[yourTintColor set];
[newImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, newImage.size.height)];
newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

_imgView.image = newImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

First set the image in UIImageView then use below code snippet.

```
imgView.image = [imgView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[imgView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```